# how to accept multiple lines of input just once and making sure the user is not asked for input once again

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have tried to solve the 3n+1 problem, and got very close. I think what happens here is the answer should accept multiple lines of input at once  should not ask the user to give input again. I have tried the nextLine() method in a loop conditioned by the hasNextLong(), but the problem is whenever it does not find any more long types, it asks the user to give another input instead of breaking the loop. Is there any way to make sure it takes input only once, regardless of how many lines the user inputs?

The loop breaks if I enter a String. What I want to do is break when only the first input has no more long variables to deal with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class te{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner key=new Scanner (new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
    String s="";
    while(key.hasNextInt()){
      System.out.println("Entered loop");
      s=s+""+key.nextLong();
    }   
    System.out.println(s); 
  }
}
```

Comment: @peeskillet, he may be referring to this problem: 
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36

Comment: Please elaboorate what you mean by "break when only the first input has no more long variables to deal with."

Comment: actually what i meant is ... hasNextLong() continues to deal with the long variables as long as it finds any... and when it doesnot find any more it asks the user to give another input... now what i wanted is instead of asking the user i wanted the loop to be broken at that point

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your trying to accomplish, but to answer this problem:

> *"..whenever it does not find any more long types, it asks the user to give another input instead of breaking the loop."*

I just used a `try/catch` block. If the input is not a number, it breaks the loop. You can keep inputting numbers and hitting enter, and if an input is not a number, the loop will `break;` and it will print out the concatenated numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = "";
        System.out.println("Enter Numbers: ");

        while (true) {
            try {
                s += String.valueOf(scanner.nextInt());  // if input is not an int
            } catch (Exception ex) {                     // it will throw exception
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Scanning a line**

```
Scanner input = Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printline("Enter some numbers: ");

String line = scanner.nextLine();
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

while (lineScanner.hasNextLong()){
    long num = lineScanner.nextLong();
    // do something with num
}
```

Comment: thanks but i have tried these things... like breaking the loop when an blank entry is given or a string is given... but i think the uva online judge is recommending the code to take multiple line of inputs at one shot and give the result printed. so i had to break the loop which was taking input for me... once the user has hit the enter... to make sure my code will not take any more entries.

Comment: Maybe you want to post the complete instructions (verbatum), if it it's not too long. At least the relevant parts.

Comment: Scanner dd=new Scanner (new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
   while (dd.hasNextLong()) {
      cas[0][aa]=dd.nextLong();
      cas[1][aa]=dd.nextLong();
     result[aa]=check(cas[0][aa],cas[1][aa]);
     aa++;
   }

i want this loop to be able to take only one input and break instead of asking another one to the user

Comment: But are they on the same line? or is there an enter pressed for each ling and they are on separate lines?

Comment: or any possible ways how i can take multiple lines of input but with one shot only... and save them.. and will not ask the user to give input again .. like asking the user to give a empty entry or some thing like that... 

in summary i want a multiple line of input.. with only one shot.. not asking for any perticular termination code from the user.. but to self terminate my input taking just after the first entry

Comment: no no  .. u can see the ";" sign among them... thoug being in the same line does not have any thing to do with the code ....they are of course on different lines ..

Comment: Do the instructions say they the input will be coming from different lines? Because you can take a whole line input and Scan that line. Sorry, I don't think I'm following correctly.

Comment: You should try and fix your post to be more understandable with some example inputs and what you expect to do with those inputs and whatever constraints come with the instructions.